# Show only products on a new category page which have a certain product attribute enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-collection, category-products

I want to create a new category page which shows all products which have a certain product attribute (speed_delivery) set to yes.

I was thinking about to create an empty category, catch its product collection via observer and modify it (filtering by the attribute)

Unfortunately this approach doesn't seem to work because it looks like there is no event to hook into the category product collection (https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/)

How would you solve it? Do I have to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getProductCollection()`. I can't think of a better approach at the moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event.

This event is dispatched in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php::_beforeToHtml` and let you modify the product collection.

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work. It turned out it was a custom overwrite..so your answer is correct.